# How to fix namespace issues after TFS check-ins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

In setting up a solution for multiple developers, after checking in then checking out on another system, I consistently get the following error:

```
    The type or namespace name 'OData' does not exist in the namespace
'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Without checking in the `bin` folder, how can this be resolved on the working dev machine?

Comment: You need to ascertain where the assembly is on the working machine? Is it part of a NuGet package, is it part of someone's VS 2015 installation, and you don't have 2015? Googling for System.Web.Http.OData seems to hint at it been moved around. You're probably best ignoring the TFS part of this and sharing a lot more details about your projects - are they ASP.Net 5 for example.

Comment: Shifted from MVC4 to 5.  I was also experiencing this previously.

Comment: Best bet is to get the person who's machine it works on to find out where that reference is been resolved from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the System.Web.Http.OData namespace is from Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData which you can install from NuGet. So, to  correct your current issue, right click the MVC project on that machine, select Manage NuGet Package, find Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get visual studio to download the Nuget packages when you do a build locally, you can enable this through

Tools > NuGet Package Manager >Package Manager Settings

[image]

That way you're packages are not added to TFS and anything that your colleagues add to the solution will be automatically downloaded when you rebuild the code, when you first check out from source control